# Parse into a complex struct with boost::spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, abnf

I have an input encoded with ABNF grammar rules (it is MEGACO protocol):

```
!/3 [15.232.33.21]:2134
T=173619123
{
    C=230234621
    {
        PR=9,
        MF=ip/187/6/23045241
        {
           ...
        },
        MF=ip/187/6/23045242
        {
```

I want to parse it into a complex struct with boost::spirit, pseudo-code:

```
megaco
{
    param1
    param2
    {
        param1
        param2
        list of param3
            param3-1
            {
                param4
                ...
            }
            param3-2
            {
                ...
            }
    }
}
```

It should be noted that the grammar is complex and contains a lot of alternatives, levels and sequences. I am not sure how to create a boost::spirit parser to decode such a message level by level saving necessary values in the process.

Also I am not sure that boost::spirit is the right tool for it.

So how should I do it?

UPDATE: I want to thanks sehe for the great example, still the main task is to populate some structure with the values from the message. The only possible way I see now is to use BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT with a lot of structs using boost::variant for alternative and std::vector for lists of items. Am I right?

Comment: Well. Here's a "first". I'm unable to post my answer because the code is too long. Only 966 more chars to shave off now

Comment: On a side note, why not use an existing library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironically, heading over to [Appendix B.2 of RFC 3525](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3525#appendix-B.2), and implementing the bulk of it superficially¹ it turns out your sample snippet is invalid.

It was missing `ammParameter`, that's not optional as soon as you have the opening `{`:

[image]

So, fixing the snippet, here's something to get you started. It's only 850 lines of code because the spec is lengthy:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f8ac59cf7c7b344)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It> struct Megaco {

struct Tokens {
    Tokens() {
        using namespace qi;
        auto SafeChar = copy(alnum | char_("-+&!_/'?@^`~*$\\()%|."));
        auto RestChar = copy(char_(";[]{}:,#<>="));
        auto WSP         = copy(char_(" \t"));
        COMMENT      = ';' >> *(SafeChar | RestChar | WSP | '"') >> (eol|eoi);

        SEP = +(WSP | COMMENT | eol);
        LWSP = *(WSP | COMMENT | eol);
        NAME = raw [ alpha >> repeat(0,63) [alnum|'_'] ];

        // Note - The double-quote character is not allowed in quotedString.
        quotedString = '"' >> *(SafeChar | RestChar | WSP) >> '"';
        VALUE       = quotedString | lexeme[+SafeChar];
        octetString = *("\\}" | char_("\x01-\x7C\x7E-\xFF"));
    
        MTPToken=no_case["MTP"];
        H221Token=no_case["H221"];
        H223Token=no_case["H223"];
        H226Token=no_case["H226"];
        V18Token=no_case["V18"];
        V22Token=no_case["V22"];
        V22bisToken=no_case["V22b"];
        V32Token=no_case["V32"];
        V32bisToken=no_case["V32b"];
        V34Token=no_case["V34"];
        V76Token=no_case["V76"];
        V90Token=no_case["V90"];
        V91Token=no_case["V91"];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                // snipped for Stack Overflow, see Coliru
           )
    }
  protected:
    using Token = qi::rule<It>;
    Token COMMENT, SEP, LWSP;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> NAME, quotedString, VALUE, octetString;
    #define TOK(name,long,short) name##Token{qi::no_case[qi::lit(#long)|#short]},
    Token
        TOK(Add,Add,A) TOK(Audit,Audit,AT) TOK(AuditCap,AuditCapability,AC) TOK(AuditValue,AuditValue,AV) TOK(Auth,Authentication,AU)
        TOK(Bothway,Bothway,BW) TOK(Brief,Brief,BR) TOK(Buffer,Buffer,BF) TOK(Ctx,Context,C) TOK(ContextAudit,ContextAudit,CA)
        TOK(DigitMap,DigitMap,DM) TOK(Disconnected,Disconnected,DC) TOK(Delay,Delay,DL) TOK(Duration,Duration,DR) TOK(Embed,Embed,EM)
        TOK(Emergency,Emergency,EG) TOK(Error,Error,ER) TOK(EventBuffer,EventBuffer,EB) TOK(Events,Events,E) TOK(Failover,Failover,FL)
        TOK(Forced,Forced,FO) TOK(Graceful,Graceful,GR) TOK(HandOff,HandOff,HO) TOK(ImmAckRequired,ImmAckRequired,IA)
        TOK(Inactive,Inactive,IN) TOK(Isolate,Isolate,IS) TOK(InSvc,InService,IV) TOK(InterruptByEvent,IntByEvent,IBE)
        TOK(InterruptByNewSignalsDescr,IntBySigDescr,IBS) TOK(KeepActive,KeepActive,KA) TOK(Local,Local,L) TOK(LocalControl,LocalControl,O)
        TOK(LockStep,LockStep,SP) TOK(Loopback,Loopback,LB) TOK(Media,Media,M) TOK(Megacop,MEGACO,!) TOK(Method,Method,MT)
        TOK(MgcId,MgcIdToTry,MG) TOK(Mode,Mode,MO) TOK(Modify,Modify,MF) TOK(Modem,Modem,MD) TOK(Move,Move,MV)
        TOK(Mux,Mux,MX) TOK(Notify,Notify,N) TOK(NotifyCompletion,NotifyCompletion,NC) TOK(ObservedEvents,ObservedEvents,OE) TOK(Oneway,Oneway,OW)
        TOK(OnOff,OnOff,OO) TOK(OtherReason,OtherReason,OR) TOK(OutOfSvc,OutOfService,OS) TOK(Packages,Packages,PG) TOK(Pending,Pending,PN)
        TOK(Priority,Priority,PR) TOK(Profile,Profile,PF) TOK(Reason,Reason,RE) TOK(Recvonly,ReceiveOnly,RC) TOK(Reply,Reply,P)
        TOK(Restart,Restart,RS) TOK(Remote,Remote,R) TOK(ReservedGroup,ReservedGroup,RG) TOK(ReservedValue,ReservedValue,RV) TOK(Sendonly,SendOnly,SO)
        TOK(Sendrecv,SendReceive,SR) TOK(Services,Services,SV) TOK(ServiceStates,ServiceStates,SI) TOK(ServiceChange,ServiceChange,SC)
        TOK(ServiceChangeAddress,ServiceChangeAddress,AD) TOK(SignalList,SignalList,SL) TOK(Signals,Signals,SG) TOK(SignalType,SignalType,SY)
        TOK(Stats,Statistics,SA) TOK(Stream,Stream,ST) TOK(Subtract,Subtract,S) TOK(SynchISDN,SynchISDN,SN) TOK(TerminationState,TerminationState,TS)
        TOK(Test,Test,TE) TOK(TimeOut,TimeOut,TO) TOK(Topology,Topology,TP) TOK(Trans,Transaction,T) TOK(ResponseAck,TransactionResponseAck,K)
        TOK(Version,Version,V) MTPToken, H221Token, H223Token, H226Token, V18Token, V22Token, V22bisToken,
        V32Token, V32bisToken, V34Token, V76Token, V90Token, V91Token;

    // The values 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFE and 0xFFFFFFFF are reserved.
    struct SpecialContexts : qi::symbols<char, uint32_t> {
        enum { NULL_, CHOOSE = 0xFFFFFFFEl, ALL = 0xFFFFFFFFl };
        SpecialContexts() { this->add
            ("$", CHOOSE)
            ("*", ALL)
            ("-", NULL_);
        }
    } SpecialContext;
};

struct Parser : Tokens, qi::grammar<It> {
    using Tokens::LWSP;
    using Tokens::SEP;
    using Tokens::SpecialContext;
    using Tokens::NAME;
    using Tokens::VALUE;
    using Tokens::quotedString;
    using Tokens::octetString;

    Parser() : Parser::base_type(megacoMessage) {
        using namespace qi;

        auto LBRKT   = copy(LWSP >> '{' >> LWSP);
        auto RBRKT   = copy(LWSP >> '}' >> LWSP);
        auto EQUAL   = copy(LWSP >> '=' >> LWSP);
        auto COMMA   = copy(LWSP >> ',' >> LWSP);
        auto INEQUAL = copy(LWSP >> char_("><#") >> LWSP);
        auto LSBRKT  = copy(LWSP >> '[' >> LWSP);
        auto RSBRKT  = copy(LWSP >> ']' >> LWSP);
        auto LPAREN  = copy(LWSP >> '(' >> LWSP);
        auto RPAREN  = copy(LWSP >> ')' >> LWSP);
        auto PIPE    = copy(LWSP >> '|' >> LWSP);

        megacoMessage = LWSP >> -(authenticationHeader >> SEP) >> message;

        authenticationHeader 
            = Tokens::AuthToken
            >> EQUAL
            >> ("0x" >> repeat(8)[xdigit]) 
            >> ':' 
            >> ("0x" >> repeat(8)[xdigit])
            >> ':' 
            >> repeat(24,64)[xdigit]
            ;

        message 
            = Tokens::MegacopToken >> '/' >> Version >> SEP >> mId >> SEP
            >> messageBody;

        mId
            = ((domainAddress | domainName) >> -(':' >> portNumber)) 
            | mtpAddress 
            | deviceName
            ;

        domainName           
            = '<' >> alnum >> repeat(0,63)[char_("a-zA-Z0-9.-")] >> '>';
        deviceName
            = pathNAME.alias();
        pathNAME // TODO total lenght limit according to RFC comment
            = -lit('*') >> NAME >> *char_("/*a-zA-Z0-9_$") >> -('@' >> pathDomainName);

        pathDomainName = raw [(alnum|'*') >> repeat(0,63)[alnum|'-'|'*'|'.'] ];

        ContextID = SpecialContext | UINT32;

        domainAddress = '[' >> (IPv4address | IPv6address) >> ']';

        // RFC2373 contains the definition of IP6Addresses.
        IPv6address   = hexpart >> - (':' >> IPv4address);
        IPv4address   = V4hex >> '.' >> V4hex >> '.' >> V4hex >> '.' >> V4hex;
        V4hex         = qi::uint_parser<uint8_t, 10, 1, 3>{}; // "0".."255"

        hexpart = raw [
                  "::" >> -hexseq
                | hexseq >> "::" >> -hexseq
                | hexseq
            ];

        hexseq = raw[ uint_parser<uint16_t, 16, 1, 4>{} % ':' ];

        portNumber = UINT16;

        // TODO constraint checking?
        // To octet align the mtpAddress the MSBs shall be encoded as 0s.
        // An octet shall be represented by 2 hex digits.
        mtpAddress 
            = Tokens::MTPToken 
            >> LBRKT
            >> uint_parser<uint32_t, 16, 4, 8>{}
            >> RBRKT
            ;

        messageBody = errorDescriptor | transactionList;

        transactionList      = +( transactionRequest | transactionReply |
                               transactionPending | transactionResponseAck );
        //Use of response acks is dependent on underlying transport

        transactionPending   = Tokens::PendingToken >> EQUAL >> transactionID >> LBRKT >> RBRKT;

        transactionResponseAck = Tokens::ResponseAckToken 
            >> LBRKT >> (transactionAck % COMMA) >> RBRKT;
        transactionAck = transactionID | (transactionID >> "-" >> transactionID);

        transactionRequest   = Tokens::TransToken >> EQUAL >> transactionID >> LBRKT
                               >> (actionRequest % COMMA) >> RBRKT;

        actionRequest        = Tokens::CtxToken >> EQUAL >> ContextID >> LBRKT >> ((
                               contextRequest >> -(COMMA  >> commandRequestList))
                               | commandRequestList) >> RBRKT;

        contextRequest    = ((contextProperties >> -(COMMA >> contextAudit))
                    | contextAudit);

        contextProperties    = contextProperty % COMMA;

        // at-most-once
        contextProperty    = (topologyDescriptor | priority | Tokens::EmergencyToken);

        contextAudit   = Tokens::ContextAuditToken 
            >> LBRKT >> (contextAuditProperties % COMMA) >> RBRKT;

        // at-most-once
        contextAuditProperties = ( Tokens::TopologyToken | Tokens::EmergencyToken | Tokens::PriorityToken );

        // "O-" indicates an optional command
        // "W-" indicates a wildcarded response to a command
        commandRequestList = -lit("O-") >> -lit("W-") >> commandRequest
                             >> *(COMMA >> -lit("O-") >> -lit("W-") >> commandRequest);

        commandRequest      = ( ammRequest | subtractRequest | auditRequest |
                                notifyRequest | serviceChangeRequest);

        transactionReply     = Tokens::ReplyToken >> EQUAL >> transactionID >> LBRKT
                          >> -( Tokens::ImmAckRequiredToken >> COMMA)
                        >> ( errorDescriptor | actionReplyList ) >> RBRKT;

        actionReplyList      = actionReply % COMMA ;


        actionReply          = Tokens::CtxToken >> EQUAL >> ContextID >> LBRKT
                          >> ( ( errorDescriptor | commandReply ) |
                 (commandReply >> COMMA >> errorDescriptor) ) >> RBRKT;

        commandReply      = (( contextProperties >> -(COMMA >> commandReplyList) ) |
                                commandReplyList );


        commandReplyList     = commandReplys % COMMA ;

        commandReplys        = (serviceChangeReply | auditReply | ammsReply |
                                notifyReply );

        //Add Move and Modify have the same request parameters
        ammRequest           = (Tokens::AddToken | Tokens::MoveToken | Tokens::ModifyToken ) >> EQUAL
                                >> TerminationID >> 
                                -(LBRKT >> (ammParameter % COMMA) >> RBRKT);

        //at-most-once
        ammParameter         = (mediaDescriptor | modemDescriptor |
                                muxDescriptor | eventsDescriptor |
                                signalsDescriptor | digitMapDescriptor |
                                eventBufferDescriptor | auditDescriptor);

        ammsReply            = (Tokens::AddToken | Tokens::MoveToken | Tokens::ModifyToken |
                                Tokens::SubtractToken ) >> EQUAL >> TerminationID >> -( LBRKT
                                >> terminationAudit >> RBRKT );

        subtractRequest      =  Tokens::SubtractToken >> EQUAL >> TerminationID
                                >> -( LBRKT >> auditDescriptor >> RBRKT);

        auditRequest         =  (Tokens::AuditValueToken | Tokens::AuditCapToken ) >> EQUAL
                                >> TerminationID >> LBRKT >> auditDescriptor >> RBRKT;

        auditReply           = (Tokens::AuditValueToken | Tokens::AuditCapToken )
                               >> ( contextTerminationAudit  | auditOther);

        auditOther           = EQUAL >> TerminationID >> -(LBRKT >> terminationAudit >> RBRKT);

        terminationAudit = auditReturnParameter % COMMA;

        contextTerminationAudit = EQUAL >> Tokens::CtxToken >> ( terminationIDList |
                               LBRKT >> errorDescriptor >> RBRKT );

        auditReturnParameter = (mediaDescriptor | modemDescriptor |
                                muxDescriptor | eventsDescriptor |
                                signalsDescriptor | digitMapDescriptor |

                           observedEventsDescriptor | eventBufferDescriptor |
                                statisticsDescriptor | packagesDescriptor |
                                 errorDescriptor | auditItem);

        auditDescriptor      = Tokens::AuditToken >> LBRKT >> -( auditItem % COMMA ) >> RBRKT;

        notifyRequest        = Tokens::NotifyToken >> EQUAL >> TerminationID
                               >> LBRKT >> ( observedEventsDescriptor
                                     >> -( COMMA >> errorDescriptor ) ) >> RBRKT;

        notifyReply          = Tokens::NotifyToken >> EQUAL >> TerminationID
                               >> -( LBRKT >> errorDescriptor >> RBRKT );

        serviceChangeRequest = Tokens::ServiceChangeToken >> EQUAL >> TerminationID
                               >> LBRKT >> serviceChangeDescriptor >> RBRKT;

        serviceChangeReply   = Tokens::ServiceChangeToken >> EQUAL >> TerminationID
                               >> -(LBRKT >> (errorDescriptor | serviceChangeReplyDescriptor) >> RBRKT);

        errorDescriptor   = Tokens::ErrorToken >> EQUAL >> ErrorCode
                            >> LBRKT >> -quotedString >> RBRKT;

        ErrorCode            = repeat(1,4)[digit]; // could be extended

        transactionID        = UINT32;

        // OTHER STUFF, DESCRIPTORS
        terminationIDList  = LBRKT >> (TerminationID % COMMA) >> RBRKT;

        TerminationID        = "ROOT" | pathNAME | "$" | "*";

        mediaDescriptor = Tokens::MediaToken >> LBRKT >> (mediaParm % COMMA) >> RBRKT;

        // at-most one terminationStateDescriptor
        // and either streamParm(s) or streamDescriptor(s) but not both
        mediaParm            = (streamParm | streamDescriptor | terminationStateDescriptor);

        // at-most-once per item
        streamParm           = (localDescriptor | remoteDescriptor | localControlDescriptor);

        streamDescriptor     = Tokens::StreamToken >> EQUAL >> StreamID 
            >> LBRKT >> streamParm >> *(COMMA >> streamParm) >> RBRKT;

        localControlDescriptor = Tokens::LocalControlToken 
            >> LBRKT >> localParm >> *(COMMA >> localParm) >> RBRKT;

        // at-most-once per item except for propertyParm
        localParm = (streamMode | propertyParm | reservedValueMode | reservedGroupMode);


        reservedValueMode    = Tokens::ReservedValueToken >> EQUAL >> ( lit("ON") | "OFF" );
        reservedGroupMode    = Tokens::ReservedGroupToken >> EQUAL >> ( lit("ON") | "OFF" );

        streamMode           = Tokens::ModeToken >> EQUAL >> streamModes;

        streamModes     = (Tokens::SendonlyToken | Tokens::RecvonlyToken | Tokens::SendrecvToken |
                               Tokens::InactiveToken | Tokens::LoopbackToken );

        propertyParm         = pkgdName >> parmValue;
        parmValue            = (EQUAL >> alternativeValue | INEQUAL >> VALUE);
        alternativeValue     = ( VALUE
                       | LSBRKT >> (VALUE % COMMA) >> RSBRKT // sublist (i.e., A AND B AND ...)
                       | LBRKT >> (VALUE % COMMA) >> RBRKT // alternatives (i.e., A OR B OR ...)
                       | LSBRKT >> VALUE >> ':' >> VALUE >> RSBRKT ) // range
                       ;
        // Note - The octet zero is not among the permitted characters in
        // octet string.  As the current definition is limited to SDP, and a
        // zero octet would not be a legal character in SDP, this is not a
        // concern.

        localDescriptor      = Tokens::LocalToken >> LBRKT >> octetString >> RBRKT;

        remoteDescriptor     = Tokens::RemoteToken >> LBRKT >> octetString >> RBRKT;

        eventBufferDescriptor= Tokens::EventBufferToken >> -( LBRKT >> eventSpec >> *( COMMA >> eventSpec) >> RBRKT );

        eventSpec      = pkgdName >> -( LBRKT >> (eventSpecParameter % COMMA) >> RBRKT );
        eventSpecParameter   = (eventStream | eventOther);

        eventBufferControl     = Tokens::BufferToken >> EQUAL >> ( "OFF" | Tokens::LockStepToken );

        terminationStateDescriptor = Tokens::TerminationStateToken >> LBRKT
                   >> terminationStateParm >> *( COMMA >> terminationStateParm ) >> RBRKT;

        // at-most-once per item except for propertyParm
        terminationStateParm = (propertyParm | serviceStates | eventBufferControl);


        serviceStates        = Tokens::ServiceStatesToken >> EQUAL >> ( Tokens::TestToken | Tokens::OutOfSvcToken | Tokens::InSvcToken );

        muxDescriptor        = Tokens::MuxToken >> EQUAL >> MuxType  >> terminationIDList;

        MuxType              = ( Tokens::H221Token | Tokens::H223Token | Tokens::H226Token | Tokens::V76Token
                                | extensionParameter );

        StreamID             = UINT16;
        pkgdName     = (PackageName >> '/' >> ItemID) //specific item
                     | (PackageName >> "/*") //all items in package
                     | "*/*" // all items supported by the MG
                     ;
        PackageName          = NAME.alias();
        ItemID               = NAME.alias();

        eventsDescriptor     = Tokens::EventsToken >> -( EQUAL >> RequestID >> LBRKT >> requestedEvent >> *( COMMA >> requestedEvent ) >> RBRKT );

        requestedEvent       = pkgdName >> -( LBRKT >> eventParameter >> *( COMMA >> eventParameter ) >> RBRKT );

        // at-most-once each of KeepActiveToken , eventDM and eventStream
        //at most one of either embedWithSig or embedNoSig but not both
        //KeepActiveToken and embedWithSig must not both be present
        eventParameter       = ( embedWithSig | embedNoSig | Tokens::KeepActiveToken | eventDM | eventStream | eventOther );

        embedWithSig         = Tokens::EmbedToken >> LBRKT >> signalsDescriptor
                                 >> -(COMMA >> embedFirst ) >> RBRKT;
        embedNoSig        = Tokens::EmbedToken >> LBRKT >> embedFirst >> RBRKT;

        // at-most-once of each
        embedFirst      = Tokens::EventsToken >> -( EQUAL >> RequestID >> LBRKT >> (secondRequestedEvent % COMMA) >> RBRKT );

        secondRequestedEvent = pkgdName >> -( LBRKT >> secondEventParameter >> *( COMMA >> secondEventParameter ) >> RBRKT );

        // at-most-once each of embedSig , KeepActiveToken, eventDM or
        // eventStream
        // KeepActiveToken and embedSig must not both be present
        secondEventParameter = ( embedSig | Tokens::KeepActiveToken | eventDM |
                                 eventStream | eventOther );

        embedSig  = Tokens::EmbedToken >> LBRKT >> signalsDescriptor >> RBRKT;

        eventStream          = Tokens::StreamToken >> EQUAL >> StreamID;


        eventOther           = eventParameterName >> parmValue;

        eventParameterName   = NAME.alias();

        eventDM              = Tokens::DigitMapToken >> EQUAL >> ( digitMapName  |
                               (LBRKT >> digitMapValue >> RBRKT ));

        signalsDescriptor    = Tokens::SignalsToken >> LBRKT >> -( signalParm % COMMA) >> RBRKT;

        signalParm           = signalList | signalRequest;

        signalRequest        = signalName >> -( LBRKT >> (sigParameter % COMMA) >> RBRKT );

        signalList           = Tokens::SignalListToken >> EQUAL >> signalListId >> LBRKT
                               >> (signalListParm % COMMA) >> RBRKT;

        signalListId         = UINT16;

        //exactly once signalType, at most once duration and every signal
        //parameter
        signalListParm       = signalRequest.alias();

        signalName           = pkgdName.alias();
        //at-most-once sigStream, at-most-once sigSignalType,
        //at-most-once sigDuration, every signalParameterName at most once
        sigParameter = sigStream | sigSignalType | sigDuration | sigOther
                    | notifyCompletion | Tokens::KeepActiveToken;
        sigStream            = Tokens::StreamToken >> EQUAL >> StreamID;
        sigOther             = sigParameterName >> parmValue;
        sigParameterName     = NAME.alias();
        sigSignalType        = Tokens::SignalTypeToken >> EQUAL >> signalType;
        signalType           = (Tokens::OnOffToken | Tokens::TimeOutToken | Tokens::BriefToken);
        sigDuration          = Tokens::DurationToken >> EQUAL >> UINT16;
        notifyCompletion     = Tokens::NotifyCompletionToken >> EQUAL >> (LBRKT
                 >> (notificationReason % COMMA) >> RBRKT);

        notificationReason   = ( Tokens::TimeOutToken | Tokens::InterruptByEventToken
                             | Tokens::InterruptByNewSignalsDescrToken
                             | Tokens::OtherReasonToken );
        observedEventsDescriptor = Tokens::ObservedEventsToken >> EQUAL >> RequestID
                           >> LBRKT >> (observedEvent % COMMA) >> RBRKT;

        //time per event, because it might be buffered
        observedEvent        = -( TimeStamp >> LWSP >> ':') >> LWSP
                               >> pkgdName >> -( LBRKT >> (observedEventParameter % COMMA) >> RBRKT );

        //at-most-once eventStream, every eventParameterName at most once
        observedEventParameter = eventStream | eventOther;

        // For an AuditCapReply with all events, the RequestID should be ALL.
        RequestID            = ( UINT32 | "*" );

        modemDescriptor      = Tokens::ModemToken >> (( EQUAL >> modemType) |
                           (LSBRKT >> (modemType % COMMA) >> RSBRKT))
                          >> -( LBRKT >> (propertyParm % COMMA) >> RBRKT );

        // at-most-once except for extensionParameter
        modemType            = (Tokens::V32bisToken | Tokens::V22bisToken | Tokens::V18Token |
                                Tokens::V22Token | Tokens::V32Token | Tokens::V34Token | Tokens::V90Token |
                              Tokens::V91Token | Tokens::SynchISDNToken | extensionParameter);

        digitMapDescriptor  = Tokens::DigitMapToken >> EQUAL
                             >> ( ( LBRKT >> digitMapValue >> RBRKT ) |
                             (digitMapName >> -( LBRKT >> digitMapValue >> RBRKT )) );
        digitMapName        = NAME.alias();
        digitMapValue       = -("T:" >> Timer >> COMMA) >> -("S:" >> Timer >> COMMA)
                           >> -("L:" >> Timer >> COMMA) >> digitMap;
        Timer               = repeat(1,2)[digit];
        // Units are seconds for T, S, and L timers, and hundreds of
        // milliseconds for Z timer.  Thus T, S, and L range from 1 to 99
        // seconds and Z from 100 ms to 9.9 s
        digitMap = (digitString |
                    LPAREN >> digitStringList >> RPAREN);
        digitStringList   = digitString >> *( PIPE >> digitString );
        digitString       = +digitStringElement;
        digitStringElement = digitPosition >> -lit('.');
        digitPosition     = digitMapLetter | digitMapRange;
        digitMapRange     = ("x" | (LSBRKT >> digitLetter >> RSBRKT));
        digitLetter       = *((digit >> "-" >> digit ) | digitMapLetter);
        digitMapLetter    = char_("0-9" //Basic event symbols
                                  "a-kA-K"
                                  "LS" // Inter-event timers (long, short)
                                  "Z" //Long duration modifier
                                  );

        //at-most-once, and DigitMapToken and PackagesToken are not allowed
        //in AuditCapabilities command
        auditItem            = ( Tokens::MuxToken | Tokens::ModemToken | Tokens::MediaToken |
                                Tokens::SignalsToken | Tokens::EventBufferToken |
                                Tokens::DigitMapToken | Tokens::StatsToken | Tokens::EventsToken |
                                Tokens::ObservedEventsToken | Tokens::PackagesToken );



        serviceChangeDescriptor = Tokens::ServicesToken 
            >> LBRKT >> serviceChangeParm >> *(COMMA >> serviceChangeParm) >> RBRKT;

        // each parameter at-most-once
        // at most one of either serviceChangeAddress or serviceChangeMgcId
        // but not both
        // serviceChangeMethod and serviceChangeReason are REQUIRED
        serviceChangeParm    = (serviceChangeMethod | serviceChangeReason |
                               serviceChangeDelay | serviceChangeAddress |
                               serviceChangeProfile | extension | TimeStamp |
                               serviceChangeMgcId | serviceChangeVersion );

        serviceChangeReplyDescriptor = Tokens::ServicesToken >> LBRKT
                             >> (servChgReplyParm % COMMA) >> RBRKT;

        // at-most-once.  Version is REQUIRED on first ServiceChange response
        // at most one of either serviceChangeAddress or serviceChangeMgcId
        // but not both
        servChgReplyParm     = (serviceChangeAddress | serviceChangeMgcId |
                               serviceChangeProfile | serviceChangeVersion |
                               TimeStamp);
        serviceChangeMethod  = Tokens::MethodToken >> EQUAL >> (Tokens::FailoverToken |
                               Tokens::ForcedToken | Tokens::GracefulToken | Tokens::RestartToken |
                               Tokens::DisconnectedToken | Tokens::HandOffToken |
                               extensionParameter);
        // A serviceChangeReason consists of a numeric reason code
        // and an optional text description.
        // A serviceChangeReason MUST be encoded using the quotedString
        // form of VALUE.
        // The quotedString SHALL contain a decimal reason code,
        // optionally followed by a single space character and a
        // textual description string.


        serviceChangeReason  = Tokens::ReasonToken  >> EQUAL >> VALUE;
        serviceChangeDelay   = Tokens::DelayToken   >> EQUAL >> UINT32;
        serviceChangeAddress = Tokens::ServiceChangeAddressToken >> EQUAL >> ( mId |
                               portNumber );
        serviceChangeMgcId   = Tokens::MgcIdToken   >> EQUAL >> mId;
        serviceChangeProfile = Tokens::ProfileToken >> EQUAL >> NAME >> '/' >> Version;
        serviceChangeVersion = Tokens::VersionToken >> EQUAL >> Version;
        extension            = extensionParameter >> parmValue;

        packagesDescriptor   = Tokens::PackagesToken 
            >> LBRKT >> packagesItem >> *(COMMA >> packagesItem) >> RBRKT;

        packagesItem         = NAME >> "-" >> UINT16;


        TimeStamp            = Date >> "T" >> Time; // per ISO 8601:1988
        // Date = yyyymmdd
        Date                 = repeat(8)[digit];
        // Time = hhmmssss
        Time                 = repeat(8)[digit];
        statisticsDescriptor = Tokens::StatsToken 
            >> LBRKT >> statisticsParameter >> *(COMMA >> statisticsParameter ) >> RBRKT;

        //at-most-once per item
        statisticsParameter  = pkgdName >> -(EQUAL >> VALUE);

        topologyDescriptor   = Tokens::TopologyToken 
            >> LBRKT >> topologyTriple >> *(COMMA >> topologyTriple) >> RBRKT;
        topologyTriple       = terminationA >> COMMA >>
                               terminationB >> COMMA >> topologyDirection;
        terminationA         = TerminationID.alias();
        terminationB         = TerminationID.alias();
        topologyDirection    = Tokens::BothwayToken | Tokens::IsolateToken | Tokens::OnewayToken;

        priority             = Tokens::PriorityToken >> EQUAL >> UINT16;

        extensionParameter   = "X" >> char_("-+") >> repeat(1,6)[alnum];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
            // snipped for Stack Overflow, see Coliru
        )

    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It> megacoMessage, message;
    qi::rule<It, uint32_t()> mtpAddress, ContextID;

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> mId, domainName, deviceName, pathNAME, domainAddress, pathDomainName,
        IPv4address, IPv6address, hexpart, hexseq;
    qi::rule<It, uint16_t()> portNumber;
    qi::rule<It, uint8_t()> V4hex;

    // implicit lexemes (no implicit whitespace allowed):
    qi::rule<It> authenticationHeader;
    qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 1, 2> Version;
    qi::uint_parser<uint32_t, 10, 1, 10> UINT32;
    qi::uint_parser<uint16_t, 10, 1, 5>  UINT16;

    // message payload
    qi::rule<It> messageBody,
        transactionList, transactionPending, transactionResponseAck, transactionAck, transactionRequest,
        actionRequest,
        contextRequest, contextProperties, contextProperty, contextAudit, contextAuditProperties,
        commandRequestList, commandRequest,
        transactionReply,
        actionReplyList, actionReply, commandReply,
        commandReplyList, commandReplys,
        ammRequest, ammParameter, ammsReply,
        subtractRequest,
        auditRequest, auditReply, auditOther,
        terminationAudit,
        contextTerminationAudit,
        auditReturnParameter, auditDescriptor, notifyRequest,
        notifyReply,
        serviceChangeRequest, serviceChangeReply,
        errorDescriptor, ErrorCode, transactionID;

    // OTHER STUFF, DESCRIPTORS
    qi::rule<It> 
        terminationIDList,
        TerminationID, mediaDescriptor,
        mediaParm, streamParm,
        streamDescriptor, localControlDescriptor, localParm,
        reservedValueMode, reservedGroupMode,
        streamMode, streamModes,
        propertyParm, parmValue, alternativeValue,
        localDescriptor, remoteDescriptor,
        eventBufferDescriptor, eventSpec, eventSpecParameter, eventBufferControl,
        terminationStateDescriptor, terminationStateParm,
        serviceStates,
        muxDescriptor, MuxType,
        StreamID,
        pkgdName, PackageName,
        ItemID,
        eventsDescriptor, requestedEvent, eventParameter,
        embedWithSig, embedNoSig, embedFirst,
        secondRequestedEvent, secondEventParameter,
        embedSig,
        eventStream, eventOther, eventParameterName, eventDM,
        signalsDescriptor, signalParm, signalRequest, signalList, signalListId, signalListParm, signalName,
        sigParameter, sigStream, sigOther, sigParameterName, sigSignalType, signalType, sigDuration,
        notifyCompletion, notificationReason,
        observedEventsDescriptor, observedEvent, observedEventParameter,
        RequestID,
        modemDescriptor, modemType,
        digitMapDescriptor, digitMapName, digitMapValue,
        Timer,
        digitMap, digitStringList, digitString, digitStringElement, digitPosition, digitMapRange, digitLetter, digitMapLetter,
        auditItem,
        serviceChangeDescriptor, serviceChangeParm, serviceChangeReplyDescriptor,
        servChgReplyParm,
        serviceChangeMethod, serviceChangeReason, serviceChangeDelay, serviceChangeAddress, serviceChangeMgcId, serviceChangeProfile, serviceChangeVersion,
        extension,
        packagesDescriptor,
        packagesItem,
        TimeStamp, Date, Time,
        statisticsDescriptor, statisticsParameter,
        topologyDescriptor, topologyTriple,
        terminationA, terminationB,
        topologyDirection,
        priority,
        extensionParameter;
};

};
int main() {
    std::string const  sample = R"(
!/3 [15.232.33.21]:2134
T=173619123
{
    C=230234621
    {
        PR=9,
        MF=ip/187/6/23045241
        {
            MD=V90
        },
        MF=ip/187/6/23045242
        {
            MD=V90
        }
    }
})";

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    Megaco<It>::Parser parser;

    It f = sample.begin(), l = sample.end();
    bool ok = qi::parse(f, l, parser);

    if (ok)
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f != l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parse success
```

---

¹ i.e. mostly dumb transformation of the productions, specifically barely no attribute handling and very heavy (e.g. no `symbols<>` for the modemtypes etc.)

Comment: I had to do some ugly compression using that `TOK` macro to fit the code in to the 30000 char limit. Please refer to the [Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f8ac59cf7c7b344) for the code as it was intended.

Comment: Managed to extract the SPIRIT_DEBUG output from Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/297cadcc4f8a3f44/output

Comment: that's very sweet of you but I don't understand how to populate the output structure with the extracted values?

Comment: I ran out of time because of that silly answer limit yesterday. Will See about attributes later.

Comment: thanks, sehe, I'm very grateful for your help. looking forward to your approach to attributes extraction

Comment: The more answers of yours I see, the more I'm convinced that you are a complete madman. Kudos to you.

Comment: @Quentin yeah, this one is a bit extensive. Cheers :)

Comment: @NikolayKovalenko Here's one example that wires the ASTs for just enough rules to demo your sample. [Coliru doesn't manage the ~2k LOC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac5ae8147a478a45) . I made the _mistake_ of basing the AST on the [ASN.1 definitions](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3525#appendix-A.2) thinking it would give me a speed boost. Rather, they turned out to be awkward (surprise) and hard to map to the grammar productions. If I'd do this again, I'd match directly onto the grammar (compare `PropertyParm` e.g.). Output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25971577/